# Excel VBA code to export chart as JPG and upload to sharepoint?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I'm using the following code to export my diagram as JPG and save it in the worksheet directory.

```
Sub exportDiagram_Click()
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim filePath As String

    Set objChrt = Sheets("Diagrams").ChartObjects("dashboardExport")
    Set myChart = objChrt.Chart

    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\export.jpg"

    myChart.Export Filename:=filePath, Filtername:="JPG"
End Sub
```

Since I uploaded this Excel file to Sharepoint my code doesn't work anymore.

How do I create this JPG file and upload it to Sharepoint from Excel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying I got the following solution which is fine for me:

```
Sub exportDiagram_Click()
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim SharepointAddress As String
    Dim objNet As Object
    Dim FS As Object

    ' output path '
    SharepointAddress = "\\sharepoint\documents\example.jpg"

        Set objChrt = Sheets("mySheet").ChartObjects("diagramExport")
        Set myChart = objChrt.Chart
        Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
        Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' remove old file from target '
    If FS.FileExists(SharepointAddress) Then
        SetAttr SharepointAddress, vbNormal
        Kill SharepointAddress
    End If

    ' export as JPG '
    myChart.Export FileName:=SharepointAddress, Filtername:="JPG"

    Set objNet = Nothing
    Set FS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now when I press the button in my Excel file it exports the `diagramExport` diagram right into my Sharepoint documents.

I hope this helps some others. Greets